# Only update field if form value exists

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm using Form Model Binding as such and updating my DB using the fill() and save() methods.

```
{{ Form::model($account) }}
  {{ Form::text('name', null, array('class'=>'class')) }}
  {{ Form::text('email', null, array('class'=>'class')) }}
  {{ Form::password('password', array('class'=>'class')) }}
  {{ Form::password('password_confirmation', array('class'=>'class')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Which fires my editAccount controller method:

```
$rules = array(
  'name' => array('required'),
  'email' => array('required'),
  'password' => array('confirmed')
);

$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

if ($validator->fails())
{
 // Redirect
}

// Save to DB
$account->fill(Input::all());
$account->save();
```

Which works fine, but if no password was supplied (because the user doesn't want to update/modify it) then the password field is set to null in the db. So, I only want the password field to update if a new password value is supplied via the form.

I know I can do the following:

```
// Set the fields manually
$account->name = Input::get('name');
$account->email = Input::get('email');

// Only update the password field if a value is supplied
if (Input::get('password')) {
    $account->password = Input::get('password');
}
$account->save();
```

However I'm wondering if there is a more cleaner way to handle this? Like an UpdateOnlyIfValueExists() method within Laravel/Eloquent.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using `Input::only('foo', 'bar')` will grab only the values needed to complete the request - instead of using `Input::all()`.

However, if 'foo' or 'bar' doesn't exist within the input, the key will exist with the value of `null`:

```
$input = Input::only('foo', 'bar');
var_dump($input);

// Outputs
array (size=2)
  'foo' => null
  'bar' => null
```

To filter in a clean way, any values with a `null` value:

```
$input = array_filter($input, 'strlen');
```

In your example, this would replace: `$account->fill(Input::all());`

Answer (score 7):

Create Base model and override update function like

```
/**
 * @param array $attributes
 * @return mixed
 */
public function update(Array $attributes = array()){
    foreach($attributes as $key => $value){
        if(!is_null($value)) $this->{$key} = $value;
    }
    return $this->save();
}
```

After use:

```
$model = Model::find($id);
$model->update(Input::only('param1', 'param2', 'param3'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this, you can validate if password is present in input, and exclude it from mass assignment. You can use Input::except and Input::only for this purpose

```
public function update ($id) {
    $user = User::findOrFail ($id);
    if (Input::get ('password') == '') {
        $user->update (Input::except ('password'));
    }
    else {
        $user->update (Input::all ());
    }

    //return something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$data = $request->password ? $request->all():$request->except('password');
$user->update($data);
```

This will only update the password if it's not null

Answer (score 1):

I would stick with your latter example. Another option would be to use a [mutator](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) which checks the value there, and doesn't update if the value is empty. But in my opinion, Eloquent should not be responsible for doing that.

I'd also avoid using ALL input with `fill()`. Choose only what you want.

Comment: Do you have any references as to why Input::all() should be avoided? I can't find any reasoning why it should be avoided.

Comment: If you have any other `User` fields that can be filled via mass assignment, someone could create an arbitrary field with that column name, and change the value without you doing any checking on it. It's just good practice to gather only what you intend on utilizing.

Comment: I understand that, but with correct use of the model's guarded or fillable properties (which I've done). Then there is inherently no security risks between Input::all and manually populating the fields.

Comment: If you were to ever add a field and change the `$fillable` array, or if you want items fillable on one form but not another, that can introduce problems. Yes, with the right steps you can protect against it and still use `Input::all()`, I'm just making a suggestion that offers additional protection. It's also more verbose about exactly what input you need, rather than just saying all. Use whichever makes you happy. ;)

Comment: I'll stop arguing after this, I promise. :) I'm taking issue with you advocating that not-doing mass assignment is more secure than doing it, that's simply not true. I agree, one can screw up mass assignment and do it "wrong", but isn't this true for anything? After all, you could do any number of a million things wrong with PHP and with your reasoning, you should be advocating PHP be thrown away in favour of a language a lot more strongly typed. So, I think your argument should be "Don't screw up mass assignment", not that it's in-secure.

Comment: Mass assignment is not the argument here. Both options -- Input::all() or Input::only() -- are utilizing mass assignment in the end. The latter, however, is explicit about which fields are implemented in that particular form/page/scenario. The benefits of which include being explicit about which form fields you expect/need (a side bonus of which is code readability), and only allowing those specific fields to be mass assigned later on, regardless of what all fields are available to be mass assigned. You can contact me however you please if you want to continue. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty shitty and common issue with Laravel (and other frameworks). My solution resembles some of the previous...

I always have the form data Input::all() stored in a variable at the beginning of the update/store methods. Since you usually need it at least twice (validate and create/update) it seems like a good practice. Then with that and before doing anything else I check in update() for the presence of the password, something like this:

```
$aFormData = Input::all();

if ( !$aFormData['password'] )
  unset( $aFormData['password'] );

... the rest of your code here using $aFormData ;) ...
```

And that's it, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

A much cleaner approach would be to use [Eloquent Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators)

Under no circumstances would you allow a `null` or an empty string as password so you can safely define the following mutator in your `Account` model.

```
// Only accept a valid password and 
// hash a password before saving
public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
{
    if ( $password !== null & $password === '' )
    {
        $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password);
    }
}
```

The above mutator will only set a password attribute if it is not `null` and an empty string. It also hashes the password before saving so you do not need to do it in your controller action or application elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Best approche is to use mutators as Noman Ur Rehman said above, but he had mistake in his code. Right one will be:

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($password){
   if ( $password !== null && $password !== '' )
      $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($password);
}
```