# not letting a value be nullable with the ->default() on migration

Tags: laravel

i've been working around and then i tried to make a migration where i establish this:

```
$table->string('company')->default('None');
$table->string('job')->default('freelancer');
```

now, that happens is that when i fill out my form, and submit it, it throws me an error message that the fields cannot be `NULL`.

So i'm a bit confused because as i know, if the fields are `NULL`, they should be saved as the `default` part of the migration establishes it.

How can i make it work?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are missing `$fillable` property in your model:

```
protected $fillable = ['company','job'];
```

Also make sure your migrations files are generating correctly. Go to the `table` and see if default values are set correctly.

[Laravel mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Comment: `protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'username',
        'email',
        'password',
        'type',
        'company',
        'job',
        'available'
    ];`

Answer (score 0):

It says if nothing passed to this column when you insert database will set default value as given. But if you try to insert NULL value to this column it will raise error.

If u want to allow NULL value on this column, you should add ->nullable(). Like that:

```
$table->string('company')->nullable()->default('None');
```

Let is try to explain more:

Pretend your "column1" is in your fillable array.
When you fill your model without column1. Laravel will generate query like

```
INSERT INTO table_name(column1) VALUES(NULL)
```

And if your column1 is not nullable, it will raise error.
if "column1" is not in $fillable array, and you fill your model without "column1", laravel generate query without "column1" like:

```
INSERT table(othercolumns ... ) VALUEs(....)
```

Column1 is not set, so MYSQL will set default value there.

Comment: also tried that and ends up saving just a `NULL` value

Comment: Yes of course. Try remove nullable column from $fillable array.

Comment: hmm? what do you mean? remove `company` and `job` from the `$fillable` in my model?

Comment: I edited my answer, and tried to explain why this error occurs. Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21222964/only-update-field-if-form-value-exists. In your case i think u should filter Requests and remove NULL values. Or you can use eloquent Mutator. Explained here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators

Comment: Can you please edit your answer and give me a working example of `INSERT table(column1, ....) values(NULL, ...)` please? i would appreciate it.