# Check the form field if the has a data

Tags: laravel

I have this controller

```
public function UpdateRequest(ClientUpdate $request){
    $res = Customer::where('id', $request->id)

        
                    ->update([
                        
                        'first_name'  => $request->new_first_name,
                        'last_name'   => $request->new_last_name,
                        'birthdate'   => $request->new_birthdate,
                        'gender'      => $request->new_gender,
                        'pending_update_info' => 2,

                    ]);}
```

I have a form that is updating a customer what i want to do is for example the new_first_name is null and the rest of the field is have a data it will only update the field that has a data on it .

My Logic is like this:

if new_first_name is null and new_last_name is null update only the new_gender and new_birthday,
same with  new_first_name is null and new_last_name is null and new_gender update only the new_birthday..

I dont know how to put in code in laravel hope you'll help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Only update field if form value exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21222964/only-update-field-if-form-value-exists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **update** by using **array concatenate Method** like following...

```
public function UpdateRequest(ClientUpdate $request){
    $updateItems = [];
    if($request->new_first_name){
       $updateItems['first_name'] = $request->new_first_name;
    }
    if($request->new_last_name){
       $updateItems['last_name'] = $request->new_last_name;
    }
    if($request->new_birthdate){
       $updateItems['birthdate'] = $request->new_birthdate;
    }
    if($request->new_gender){
       $updateItems['gender'] = $request->new_gender;
    }
    $updateItems['pending_update_info'] = 2;
    $res = Customer::where('id', $request->id)->update($updateItems);
}
```